# Scrape specific urls from a page and convert them to absolute urls

Tags: python, url, scrape

I need some help from you Pythonists: I'm scraping all urls starting with "details.php?" from [this page](http://evenementen.uitslagen.nl/2013/marathonrotterdam/uitslag01002nl.html) and ignoring all other urls.

Then I need to convert every url I just scraped to an absolute url, so I can scrape them one by one. The absolute urls start with: http://evenementen.uitslagen.nl/2013/marathonrotterdam/details.php?...

I tried using `re.findall` like this:

```
html = scraperwiki.scrape(url)
if html is not None:
    endofurl = re.findall("details.php?(.*?)>", html)
```

This gets me a list, but then I get stuck. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`urlparse.urljoin()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to create the full urls:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> base_url = 'http://evenementen.uitslagen.nl/2013/marathonrotterdam/'
>>> urlparse.urljoin(base_url, 'details.php?whatever')
'http://evenementen.uitslagen.nl/2013/marathonrotterdam/details.php?whatever'
```

You can use a list comprehension to do this for all of your urls:

```
full_urls = [urlparse.urljoin(base_url, url) for url in endofurl]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! My favorite...list comprehensions!

```
base_url = 'http://evenementen.uitslagen.nl/2013/marathonrotterdam/{0}'
urls = [base.format(x) for x in list_of_things_you_scraped]
```

I'm not a regex genius, so you may need to fiddle with `base_url` until you get it exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the final urls one by one and be done with them, you should use generator instead of the iterators.

```
abs_url = "url data"
urls = (abs_url+url for url in endofurl)
```

If you are worried about encoding the url you can use urllib.urlencode(url)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use `lxml.html` to parse html; there is [`.make_links_absolute()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links):

```
import lxml.html

html = lxml.html.make_links_absolute(html,
    base_href="http://evenementen.uitslagen.nl/2013/marathonrotterdam/")
```